# Explanation of dataFrame being reported as a list by typeof

Tags: r

When executing `typeof` on values returned by methods claiming to return `dataframes` it seems they report `list`.

```
df = read_csv('partitions.txt')

typeof(df)
[1] "list"
```

Given that parts of my code are manipulating `lists of dataframes` this is confusing: I had been thinking my code were operating at the wrong level of nesting.

OTOH I have seen in some cases the reported type *is* data.frame.  Why/when are dataframes reported as lists vs .. well.. data.frame's ?

**Answer Summary** : use `class(df)` instead of `typeof(df)` - it shows

```
class(truths)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

Comment: But they ***are*** different types .. no?  Why would `typeof` return `list` -which lacks two dimensional capabilities of dataframes - instead of `data.frame` (which lacks nesting capability of `list`'s) ? That question does not address this consideration in either the question or the answers.

Comment: No, data.frame is not a type, it is a class. All data frames have the type list. Try `typeof(data.frame(a = 1:3)`.

Comment: Ok so then `typeof` is not the tool for this job: I need to see the `class` then. This is a clear distinction to `jvm` languages where the `type` and the `class` will - subject to inheritance nuances - mean the same thing.

Comment: In the simplest sense, a data.frame is a list with certain conditions. It is a list of vectors that all have the same length. You can make this more complicated by storing (eg list elements in a data.frame vector) but this is typically discouraged for most cases.

Comment: a `data.frame` does not have nesting so in my mind it is not really a list. it is closer to a matrix.  In any case - i am still hunting for a more precise version of `typeof` that will distinguish the specific class - and thus between `list` and `data.frame`

Comment: so it is simply `class` then ..  `class(df)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"`

Comment: You can, in fact, do nesting with a data.frame.

Comment: I'm presuming you mean a specific *column* can contain a `list` or another `DataFrame`?

Comment: You are going into a fairly complicated realm. A data.frame is a list  (`is.list(dat)`) where dat is a data.frame returns TRUE. You probably have to spend some time learning about the different classes in R. S3, mostly but probably a bit of S4. I'd start with the help files `?methods`, `?"[.data.frame"` and `?inherits`. There are probably more direct references, but these will be pretty helpful

Comment: Yes, data.frame columns can be lists. Here's a data.frame where one column is a list of dataframes: `df <- data.frame(a = 1:3);
df$b <- replicate(3, data.frame(a = sample(1:100), b = sample(101:200)), simplify = F)`

Comment: i see - then the docs i looked at were oversimplifying the picture : they said explicitly that dataframes can not be used for nesting.  The docs you added above are providing some of that more complicated plane of details/information. Yea I better stay away from that while in the basics learning mode.

Comment: In R, types refer exclusively to the primitive data structures from which all other objects are implemented. They are a fairly low-level notion, referring to how data is managed in memory. Classes are much higher level, referring specifically to how primitive types are put together to produce a given set of behaviour/features. So data frames _are_ lists, they just happen to _also_ be data frames, which impose an additional set of constraints that, e.g. breaks the nesting capabilities of lists as abstract data types.

Comment: thx for the insight